# node.js C++ addon runing differently in Linux and Windows

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, linux, node.js-addon

I just started learning node.js and particularly its C++ addon. I modified the hello world example a little bit to see how it works. Then I found out it runs differently in Linux and Windows.

Basically, I added an internal function that used cout to output to the console. In Linux, the output is

```
worldtest
yes
```

but in Windows, it is

```
yes
worldtest
```

Basically the orders of the outputs are different. It seems the Windows output is what I expected it to be. Any ideas what I'm missing here?  Thanks!

hello.cc:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace v8;
using namespace std;
string changestring(string tmp);

void Method(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  string tmp=changestring("world");
  const char * c=tmp.c_str();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, c));

  }

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  exports->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, Method)->GetFunction());
}

string changestring(string tmp)
{
    cout<<"yes\n";
    return (tmp+"test\n");
    }

NODE_MODULE(hello, Init)
```

hello.js

```
var addon = require('bindings')('hello');

console.log(addon.hello()); // 'world'
```

Comment: it seems the `cout ` is procesed in different times in linux and windows  that is why you get different ordering, instead you should buffer all output and output as one unit if and when needed

Comment: Try adding `cout.flush();` after your `cout<<"yes\n";` or change the `cout<<"yes\n";` to `cout<<"yes\n"<<flush;`